# How to blink explorer in taskbar in windows

Tags: windows, web, browser

I have a web application.I want the browser window to blink in the taskbar when an activity occurs during minimize.
I do not want to blink the title using javascript(this is what I have seen in some websites and discussions)
I am only doing a research project, so I am not worried about having to install some code in the client machine. Is it possible that I allow the user to install something (like gmail notification) so that it provides the user a notification. The notification here is the blinking of the browser window.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sukesh

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write an extension for the browser.  This isn't something that can be done from the web page, but once you create and install a browser extension then you could activate it from the web page.  If your browser choice isn't limited, I'd suggest Chrome.  The Chrome Extensions community can be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you Joshua. But I need it in explorer itself.

Comment: In that case, see if this resource is helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587(v=vs.85).aspx